# tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid int32: 1 0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

My .**CSV** file contains the data look like this ...
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

I am trining to read this .CSV file by the following code

```
filename = "alpha_test.csv"
#setup text reader
file_length = file_len(filename)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=0)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)

#setuo text reader
listoflists = []
a_list = []
for i in range(0,49):
        listoflists.append((list([0])))


record_defaults =listoflists


data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row,record_defaults=record_defaults,field_delim='\t')
#turn features back into a tensor
features = tf.pack(data)

print("loading "+ str(features)+ "line(s)\n")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    #start populating filename queue
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners()

    for i in range(file_length):
        example = sess.run([features])
        print(example)


    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join()
    print("\ndone loading")
```

But it gives the follwing error

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempted to use a closed Session.
Traceback (most recent call last):......


tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid int32: 1   0
     [[Node: DecodeCSV = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], field_delim="\t", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderRead:1, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_1, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_2, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_3, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_4, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_5, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_6, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_7, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_8, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_9, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_10, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_11, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_12, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_13, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_14, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_15, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_16, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_17, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_18, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_19, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_20, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_21, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_22, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_23, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_24, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_25, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_26, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_27, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_28, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_29, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_30, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_31, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_32, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_33, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_34, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_35, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_36, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_37, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_38, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_39, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_40, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_41, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_42, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_43, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_44, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_45, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_46, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_47, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_48)]]
Caused by op u'DecodeCSV', defined at:
```

I have tested with the follwing data

```
1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1
```

but it gives the same error

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Comment: You need to run features within a TF session (e.g. rval= sess.run(features)) and also setup a coordinator and start queue runners. See the CSV Files section of the [Reading Data Howto](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html)  for an example.

Comment: The changes you made look right. For some reason the decode_csv thread seems to be crashing. Perhaps 'record_defaults' is incorrect. For example, does the csv really have 49 entries per row? And is the CSV file really tab delimited? When I run this with a small test csv and ensure that my parameters are consistent it works. When I have wrong parameters I get the error you got.

Comment: this file is tab seperated and the csv have 49 entity per row. I am confused to initialize tensor object list for record_defaults .

Comment: The record_defaults is used to tell the decoder what to do if a value is missing from a particular line(s). The way you set it will return a 0 as int32 for any missing values. [ [0.0], [0.0], [0.0] ...] will return float32 0's for any missing values. [ [], [], [], ... ] will return an error if any value is missing. The only other thing I can think of is to add the path to the csv filename to be sure that the code is able to find and open the csv file.

Comment: I have tested with a small dataset and i included it here . But gives the same problem @Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason for the issue you see is that the 1 and 0 in the first line of your file are actually separated by 3 spaces, not a tab. Note how the `field_delim` is properly set to `\t` in your call to `decode_csv`, but the value it seems to read is `1   0`. This is precisely what would happen if the 1 and 0 were separated by three spaces, and the next 0 was separated with a tab.

Make sure the file contains no spaces, and all the delimiters are in fact tabsl

Comment: I have tested with a small data with tap separated space .. but it gives the same error

Comment: Can you upload this small data set to ideone or drop box?